# Primefaces datatable: what 'onRowSelectUpdate="display"' means?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using the primefaces datatable and I've seen many times the onRowSelectUpdate event calling "display"?

What "display" means? is it a public method of the component or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers the ID of the component which is to be ajax-updated whenever you select a row. For example, a detail display.

```xml
<p:dataTable id="mytable" onRowSelectUpdate="mydisplay">
    ...
</p:dataTable>
...
<p:someComponent id="mydisplay">
    <p>This component will be ajax-updated whenever a row is selected.
</p:someComponent>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the PrimeFaces user guide, page 127:

> Component(s) to update instantly after a row is selected.

Sounds like it works in the same way as the Ajax `update` attribute, but is activated when a row is selected in a data table. I've never used it myself so I don't have any code samples to share.